# Sencha pop over on list itemtap

Tags: list, sencha-touch, extjs

In my application i have a list. I want to show a pop over (overlay) when an item is tapped. It works for some items but for some items the overlay goes right to the list item.

Note: I want to show an overlay with arrow pointing to current selected item.
Here is my code:

```
var overlay = new Ext.Panel({
       floating: true,
       modal: true,
       width: 100,
       height: 100,
       scroll: false});

var list = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {

   store: myStore,
   itemTpl: "{firstName} {lastName}",

   listeners:  {
        itemtap: function (list, index, element, event) {
        // Grab a reference the record.
        var record = list.getRecord(element);

        // First, we update the the overlay with the proper record (data binding).  
        overlay.update(record.data);
        overlay.showBy(element, 'fade'); 
        list.doComponentLayout();           
    }
}});
```

Problem may be i am not getting the list item correctly. I just used the current element here. I also tried list.getNode(index) but it does the same thing. Can anyone guide me in right direction?

Tarun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `false` to the show by function i.e. `overlay.showBy(element, 'fade',false);`

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-showBy

Comment: Oh! how foolish I am.. Thanks llya.

Comment: The solution worked perfect but when i extended my panel to have buttons in vbox layout, the height of the panel shown reduces randomly. i.e. for some items it shows perfect with a arrow panel and three buttons stacked vertically but for some items specially item at the bottom of list the panel height reduces?? I can't recognize this random behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my panel code.

```
var overlay = new Ext.Panel({
// We'll set the image src attribute's value programmatically.
//dock:'left',
floating: true,
modal: true,
width: 138,
height: 140,
scroll: false,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align:'center',
    pack:'center'
},
//defaults:{flex:1},
items:[
    {xtype: 'spacer'},
    {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui:'action',
            height:30,
            width:103,
            id: 'profileButton',
            text: 'Profile'
    },
    {xtype: 'spacer'},
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        ui:'action',
        height:30,
        width:103,
        id: 'positionsButton',
        text: 'Positions'
    },
    {xtype: 'spacer'},
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        ui:'action',
        height:30,
        width:103,
        id: 'actionButton',
        text: 'Action'
    },
    {xtype: 'spacer'}
]});
```